# Component duplicates when radio button is clicked(Wicket)

Tags: java, wicket

I have this code that hides other fields when radio button is clicked.
It worked on the textfield, but somehow it duplicates the dropdownfield

```
isAvailable.add(new AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4154749887506180749L;

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        if(isAvailable.getModelObject().equals(YesOrNo.YES.getKey())) {
            number.setVisible(true);
            currency.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            number.setVisible(false);
            currency.setVisible(false);
        }
        target.add(number);
        target.add(currency);
    }

});
```

Comment: I'd doublecheck that the markup ids are unique.

Comment: sorry. I kinda don't get it though. how do you check if they are unique?

Comment: View the source of the generated HTML in the browser and assert that the `id` attribute values are unique for all HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apache Wicket User Guide (Model forms)](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/wicket/common/site/trunk/_site/guide/guide/single.html#modelsforms_5) I think you need to overwrite `wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications()` method in your radio button and return true. It's because you have to notify the web server when the selected option changes.

Comment: This answer is low quality and should explain why this solution is relevant or risks deletion as a low quality answer.